# Passing list to in line query to insert in database

Tags: sql-server

Rather than hard code, I need to sent list of items can any once please suggest

```
dbCommand.CommandText = @"
declare @p1 as UDTS.udtTblIDList
insert into @p1 values(3357393323200000003)
insert into @p1 values(3357393323200000006)
insert into @p1 values(3357393323200000007)

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#ltblWorkingPaperLocation') IS NOT NULL

drop table #ltblWorkingPaperLocation

 create table #ltblWorkingPaperLocation  
 (WorkingPaperID BIGINT NOT NULL,    
 WorkingPaperLocation NVARCHAR(500))  ;  

exec PROCS.UspEngagementIndexItemFileCheck_GetWorkingPaperLocation 5000001719,@p1

select * from #ltblWorkingPaperLocation "

 dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PidEngagementfileID", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = engagementID });
```

Comment: insert into p1 values(3357393323200000003)
insert into p1 values(3357393323200000006)
insert into p1 values(3357393323200000007) rather than passing like this i have to change it in generic

Comment: Here's the relevant doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters